# Soundpool how to

Tags: java, android

What is better:

1. Creating my soundpool and loading my sounds in the `onCreate` and releasing it in the `onDestroy`
2. Creating it in the `onResume` and releasing it in the `onPause` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach will be creating the soundpool in the `onCreate`. This way you will avoid creating a new soundpool eveytime you resume a `Fragment` or an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

It related your work. But exactly you need to handle this soundpool in all of these 4 states. I recommended below cycle

```
@onCreate(){
 //initalize all soundpool configuration
}

@onPause(){

 //stop() or pause() soundpool related tasks acording to your needs
}

@onResume(){
 //play() or continue task you hold 
}

@onDestroy(){
 //close all threads related to sound pool
}
```

this will help to avoid soundpool initializing time in onResume() state.

**PS**: Do not use this soundpool threads with a large number of sound sprites. It is a bit of unstable and it provides some ambiguous behaviour